# How to create avd in android

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I am new comer in android developement . I install android sdk in eclipse and just run hello world application. Then Im getting a warning to install avd.
How to install avd in eclipse?
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Android, And dear **what is that warning actually?**

Comment: I mean , I couldnt run the application without avd.

Comment: To run android application, you must have either Android Virtual Device (i.e. Emulator) or a Real android device (i.e. Mobile/Tablet).

Comment: thanks paresh ,I just begin to study android developement today.

Comment: sure paresh. I expect ur help in future also.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please Do following stesps in your Eclipse

- Go to Windows Menu and Select "Android SDK and AVD Manager" Option
- From the right-top corner select "New" Command Button.
- It will open a new dialogbox like below.
  [image]
- Give the proper values as shown in Image and done.

Comment: Thanks! Stupid me, CPU/ABI is blank by default by me, so it said it couldn't create a CPU... +1

Comment: @11684 My CPU/ABI list is completely blank. I have no options to select. Do you have any suggestions for me? I did ask here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003009/android-virtual-device-manager-cannot-create-avd#comment19550302_14003009

Answer (score 2):

In eclipse::

Windows -> AVD Manager -> New.

Specify Device Name,
Select a target

Specify some size for SD Card. e.g. 128 MB