# Android Virtual Device Manager: Cannot create AVD

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

When I try to create an AVD in the AVD manager, I can't get the OK button un-greyed.

My problem sounds similar to [AVD Manager - Cannot Create Android Virtual Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13959128/avd-manager-cannot-create-android-virtual-device) but sadly the solution is not the same, or it would be fixed already. I checked the answer offered here, and I have already installed `ARM EABI v7a System Image`.

From what I've read so far, I suspect the problem is that my CPU/ABI dropdown list is empty.

Unfortunately, I haven't figured out what to do to fix that.

Update: I've found that I can fill the CPU/ABI dropdown by selecting one of the preset phone types.

Comment: @appubala 4.2, by memory

Comment: did you check your eclipse plugin is uptodate

Comment: @appubala Do you mean the ADT plugin? Where can I check that?

Comment: eclipse:-help->check for updates

Comment: @appubala ADT was up to date. Eclipse had an update. I also installed more API versions. My CPU/ABI list is still empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I select one of the pre-set options in the Device dropdown, all of the other fields autofill. It is possible to create new Device types using the Device Definitions tab of the AVD Manager.

Comment: When I try that, it is still greyed out.