# Cannot create or edit Android Virtual Devices (AVD) from Eclipse, ADT 22.6

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt, android-virtual-device

This problem sounds similar to a [few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13959128/avd-manager-cannot-create-android-virtual-device) [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003009/android-virtual-device-manager-cannot-create-avd), except in my case the OK button is not grey-ed out. But for those who would rather not click the links...

Trying to create or edit an AVD from within Eclipse, after entering my settings, the "OK" button seems to be "clickable", but when I click it absolutely nothing happens. [image: clickable but useless]

I've made sure I have the appropriate system images installed, and that the target platform matches the API being used. Clearly a CPU has been chosen, skin set, etc... all the things that would make the OK button greyed out, which it's not.

I can create/edit AVDs if I run the AVD manager from *outside* eclipse, so this isn't the end of the world, but I feel there's a solution to this particular problem and I want to help solve it.

I've tried running eclipse as an administrator (that's what stopped the AVD manager from crashing outside of eclipse). I've tried just waiting around, or clicking multiple times. Looking at the Task Manager, no new processes begin when I click OK, nor does eclipse's CPU or RAM usage increase at all. The "Edit Android Virtual Device" window doesn't even go away.

Any clues?

(Running Indigo with the ADT plugin, btw, not the bundled version, which failed to work in a different way. Java 1.6.0 45. Windows 8, unfortunately. Plenty of RAM etc)

Comment: AOSP tracker bug: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66661

Comment: Great, I just started Android Development today and this is a great start, what a coincidence, also having the same issue.

Comment: Issue sorted! by upgrading to 'Android SDK tools' 22.6.1 in 'Android SDK Manager' and then don't forget to 'Check for Updates' in ADT Eclipse.

Answer (score 69):

### **THIS IS A POSSIBLE WORKAROUND FOR BUGS IN ADT 22.6.0 ONLY, THESE BUGS SUBSEQUENTLY FIXED IN FOLLOWING BUILDS**

**Download and install new ADT v22.6.1 from [here (zip)](http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-22.6.1.zip) or use SDK manager to update**

Seems like some bug from Google side, this problem found after **"ADT 22.6"** update. Widely reported on **"Android Open Source Project - Issue Tracker"** and nobody properly answered it yet.

However I was partially successful to create an AVD by opening **"AVD manager.exe"** from **"Android SDK"** for creating new AVD try to open directly AVD Manager.exe in SDK folder.

May be we have to wait for any conformation from **Android community**

Worked for me, sort of.. .

**(Windows 8.1 Pro 64 Bit, Java JDK 1.7 Update 25, Eclipse Standard Kepler Service Release 1, Android Development Toolkit 22.6.0.v201403010043-1049357)**

**Update 1**

Further research revealed that launching **AVD Manager** from **SDK Manager (Tools --> Manage AVDs...)** also works without any problems.

**Update 2**

More bad news is AVD creation not working from **command line tool** too.

**Update 3**

Assuming some parameter passed during launching **AVD manager** from **Eclipse** causes these problems

**Update 4**

Updated **Java** to **JDK 1.7 Update 51** and **Eclipse Standard SDK** to **Kepler Service Release 2** their latest and no resolution to the problems. Also tested under **Debian** and same results obtained.

**Update 5**

At [**https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66661**](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66661) android project members conforms the problems and promises to fix by upcoming versions of ADT (22.6.1 - 22.6.3). At the mean time I would suggest to roll-back **ADT** to a lower version [**version 22.3.0**](https://dl.google.com/android/ADT-22.3.0.zip)

To uninstall current ADT go to

**Help --> About Eclipse --> Installation Details --> Android Development Tools --> Uninstall**

I may suggest uninstalling whole packages from Android **(DDMS, Hierarchy Viewer, NDT, Traceview, OpenGL ES..etc..)** to avoid any possible compatibility issues and install a fresh new ADT from above link through **archive installation method**.

Hope this will solve this problem temporarily. And wait for new release of ADT [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html).

**Update 6**

New **ADT**, **version 22.6.1** is out now which will solve these problems

Comment: I just got this bug after updating my ADT to 22.6 version. However my problem is solved now by this simple remedy :)

Comment: This solution works for me also. If nothing else, at least we can still test on PC. It's just an inconvenience

Comment: Opening from 'Tools' menu in SDK Manager also worked for me as well. Glad to solve the issue, but so weird.

Comment: i have encounter same problem . how can i roll back may ADT ?

Comment: @yashwanth Krishnan i got this error when i try to create a AVD help pls---No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt,22.3.0.v201310242005-887826

Comment: @JeremiahMe Are you sure you got this error when trying to create an AVD or during archive installation itself ?

However for the second case this may work

Help > Install New Software

Uncheck "Contact all update sites during install to find required software"

Reply your result

Comment: and other things like: Android SDK Tools 22.6 & Android SDK platform-tools 19.0.1. Any way to rollback to old versions? :( ..issues are killing me. i have project to submit. :''(

Comment: @ShaonHasan Did you try everything ?

Comment: ya..tried everything that came to my mind. Like first thing i did was ADT setup from archive. Than, trying to work with old SDK bundle. But its eclipse is telling me to update SDK tool. Another problem is i cant create AVD from eclipse & i can using AVD manager but with AVD manager i cant run it. I know it takes time but not like 2 hrs?!! Now plz advice me how to start my setups from the beginning. Ill follow that and let u know whether i succeeded or not.

Comment: @yashwanth-krishnan  : Please help me with my problem.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22490207/avd-not-showing-home-screen/22490485?noredirect=1#22490485

Comment: Issue sorted! by upgrading to 'Android SDK tools' 22.6.1 in 'Android SDK Manager' and then don't forget to 'Check for Updates' in ADT Eclipse.

Comment: This appears to be back in 22.6.4

Comment: I've got 22.6.4 and the solution above is not working.

Comment: uhm, how do I find my ADT version?

Comment: To know ADT version, go to

Help --> About Eclipse --> click on the android icon

Answer (score 22):

To elaborate on the statement "I can create/edit AVDs if I run the AVD manager from outside eclipse" in the OP:

Run the following on the command line

```
<android-sdk-location>/tools/android avd (on Linux in this case)
```

This launches the same AVD window you see when you click the AVD Manager icon in the eclipse toolbar. But this instance of the AVD manager does not have the bug, and you can create and run emulators as you did before the bug was introduced.

Comment: even worse java segfaults lol, but fortunately it's able to create the avd

Comment: OK so this is actually working, to create the AVD. But still the AVD won't start....

Comment: I had the same problem as well. I reduced the size of internal and external storage allocated in the emulator, and then I got it to start. I have 1024 MiB for internal storage and sdcard, and 1024 for RAM (what the units are I don't know—it doesn't say)

Comment: And sometimes it takes a very long time to start. Make sure you give it a long time if you think it's still failing to start.

Comment: lol..ya takes time!!. But doesn't mean half of the day!!. Cant open AVD from eclipse. Can create from AVD manager in sdk dir. :-(

Answer (score 7):

### 1 minute solution

I used a quick workaround where I cloned a device that already existed. The `Clone` button worked and I was able to successfully edit the clone.

### Steps:

### Select a Device by Google

[image]

### Click the "Clone..." button

[image]

### A window will pop up, click "Clone device"

[image: dddd]

### Select the newly cloned Device, it should say "... by User"

[image]

### Click the "Edit" button on the side

[image]

### There you have it, you now have your own custom virtual device

[image]

Answer (score 6):

**Update and Solution:** AsYashwanth Krishnan said, The bug in question is now fixed in later versions. I tried ADT 222.6.1 and ADT 22.6.2 , and they did not suffer from the bug of not not being able to create or edit Android Virtual Devices. The direct solution is to update you ADT to latest version, The workaround written below is left only for historical purposes.

**Historical Workaround** As @Yashwanth Krishnan said, this is a bug in ADT plugin 22.6; so best workaround is to rollback. for those asking how to rollback, here is a step-by-step guide:

First: Uninstall ADT plugin and all related plugins for android:
help->about
[image]
Installation details
[image]
Select android plugins and press uninstall button
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
Restart

Second: Download ADT 22.3.0 Archive from https://dl.google.com/android/ADT-22.3.0.zip

and install it
[image]
add repository from archive on local disk
[image]
[image]
[image]
Select android plugins
[image]

Comment: @Brother,
I am having same issue, uninstalled the 22.6.. but before installing new means. 22.3... eclipse closed hastily... now its not opening due to error eclipse executable launcher unable to locate campanian shared library...
what can I do ?

Comment: @AbdulWahab Can you post a new question on Stackoverflow with snaphots of the error and error log file located in eclipse directory and more details of what happened?

Comment: @AbdulWahab If you do not have a lot of customization in eclipse and you use it only for android development, you go go back fast to development by downloading and extracting adt-bundle from android developer website. Adb-bundle consists of    eclipse with adt and sdk preinstalled on it, from here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Answer (score 0):

INFO:

I WAS able to create an AVD successfully after clicking OK several times and modifying some of my settings as a test.

I tried yashwanth krishnan solution and tried to open the AVD Manageer.exe directly without success. The manager will not open directly for me on Windows 8 x64. It tries to open, then shuts down immediately...

Answer (score 0):

I met this issue too . The issue occurs in the latest version 22.6 which was released in March . Meanwhile I did the testing in 22.3 , the issue was not found .

So that I suggest that rollback the ADT to 22.3 and wait the new fix for 22.6

Comment: Got the WORKAROUND from google as below : WORKAROUND: In Eclipse, open the SDK Manager (via toolbar or Window menu) > Tools > Manager AVDs.
This will invoke the external version of the AVD Manager which will properly generate AVDs.
Other workaround: use the command-line version (Shell or cmd.exe, cd SDK, "tools\android.bat avd") . But I did not do the testing , so just FYI.

Comment: Any way I could roll back? I'm on OSX and I don't have the archive of ADT 22.3

Answer (score 0):

I banged my head on this for several hours until I found out that the default location was C:\username path\SDKs or something, where Android was installed on my system to D:\sdks\android_sdk_windows. So, changing the Eclipse Android directory to D:\sdks\android_sdk_windows fixed it.

I also heard that it may help things if you install the Android SDK to a path without spaces.

Hope this helps someone keep some hair.

Answer (score 0):

Today I ran into the same problem after installing Maven.  I messed around with different Path settings to get it to work and I ran into issues.  I was also trying to install the google server for GCM.  Somewhere in what I was doing I corrupted the Android Virtual Device Manager.  I searched S.O. for an answer, then I decided to follow the first rule of TechSupport.  I reinstalled the tool kit!

I went into the SDK manager and I uninstalled the tools (by clicking the Tool checkbox).  It took several minutes to delete them all.  Then I reinstalled the Tools which took about ten minutes.  I rebooted Eclipse and the AVD and worked just like it did yesterday!

This time it only took a total of twenty minutes to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [release notes](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html), this problem has been resolved in revision 22.6.1, which is now available for download.

Updated your Android SDK Tools to 22.6.1 in Eclipse by selecting `Window` > `Android SDK Manager` and follow the prompts to install the update.

After that update finishes, select `Help` > `Check for Updates` and follow the prompts to update the appropriate Eclipse components.

After completing these updates, I tested the AVD functionality and it appears to be working properly.

Answer (score 0):

i just copied the avds from a different system as descriped here: 
[Android - How to copy the emulator to a friend for testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575167/android-how-to-copy-the-emulator-to-a-friend-for-testing)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issue. I am using 23.0.2 version of android SDK.

"OK" button was disabled, but then I went to the path where android SDK was installed. In my case:

```
C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\
```

and executed AVD-Manager.exe by right clicking and selecting **Run as an Administrator**, and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the AVD cannot be created because of this following error while starting:
x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!

I was also facing this same issue. If u are facing the same, then it can be resolved by opening SDK Manager -> Under Extra -> Installed "Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM Installer). Then when creating the AVD, select the proper CPU. This should work. :-)

Answer (score -1):

For those posting that we need to set the sdcard size: I tried that and many other settings, and none of that helps. I get the NoClassDefFound Exception mentioned by mogilka, in the Error view. No configuration settings are going to fix that. It seems a bad update was pushed

Answer (score -2):

Give some value for your sd card. May be something like 100 or 200