# I am having issues with the android eclipse generating activities

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have tried re downloading it, creating new projects, and going to new > other > android activity and nothing has generated the xml or the java file for any activity. I am completely lost on what to do next.

EDIT:
I am using sdk v22.3.0-887826, I'm running windows, I have tried both updating, and re downloading the eclipse that is prebuilt for android development. There is nothing to take a screen shot of. and yes I was working yesterday on a project i started two days ago with no issues, then I decided to start a new project and now I am unable to generate the activities.

Comment: A **LOT** more information is needed to have **ANY** hope of solving this... Platform, SDK version, have you fully upgraded Android SDK and Eclipse, did it ever work, screenshots, error logs, all would help tremendously...

Comment: there i added more info. Any ideas?

Comment: Create them by yourself? Probably the best way to learn Android anyway...

Comment: What do you mean with "Generate the Activities"?

Comment: No. when i'm making a project with tons of activities I don't want to create them all myself it's to much work to do something that I shouldn't have to do.

Comment: when creating an android project it has always generated the default activity for me. also there was a simple wizard that could be used to create any other actives.

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190578/adt-will-not-allow-creation-of-android-activity

Comment: yup same issue thanks I'll follow that too

Answer (score 2):

A project with a "tons of activities" might be bad by design!? Just wondering... I mean I can not imagine a use case for tons of activities (tons would be 100+).

Anyway: Even when you have 100+, how about creating one activity and just use the built in copy & paste where you just have to rename the new pasted class?

The same with the layout files, copy it (not the content but the file in the project structure) and paste it.

After that you just need to copy&paste the `<activity>` tag in the manifest and change the names there.

It shouldn't take you longer than going through the wizard for each activity...

For the design thing: How about fragments? 100+ Activities generates the urge to use fragments...

Comment: no nothing is working, honestly I just don't want to do that because i shouldn't have to. Its like having a TV remote that won't turn on the TV. Ya I can get up and turn it on, but I shouldn't have to. The link in one of the other comments is to a different question where someone states that it is a broken feature.

Comment: And until that is fixed, you have no other choice. That is why we call that a workaround. Beside that: you can also write a small script that does that for you. Shouldnt takr you that long... Beside that what about the tons of activities? Can you share why you need so much of them?

Comment: It's not for one project. I'm working on about 20 or so different projects at the moment.

Comment: Ah ok. Basically you still need to do the workaround until the bug is fixed... or you wait which can take quite a while...

Comment: @kennedyl94 Go through this http://stackoverflow.com/a/22207516/1741671 , it might help you