# Adt doesn't create default hello world but command line does

Tags: android, eclipse-adt

My ADT worked correctly as same as whatever saw in tutorial until 2days ago when i created a project like before and also i selected "create a blank activity" and i expect it makes a default hello world project for me and a Main.java also a xml layout file, but it doesn't create this default hello world project anymore. i installed and updated Most of things in SDK Manager. i created another workspace and i did whatever i could but it doesn't create default hello world project. but when i create project from command line it works correctly and make a hello world project. why ADT doesn't do that?
it's list of installed package on my SDK manager

[image: SDK Manager list1]
[image: SDK Manager list2]

and its the project tree in ADT that is empty when i create a project with blank activity:

[image: Project tree in ADT]

But it works in commandline. i use same sdk manager from command line:

```
~/Program/Andr/adt/sdk/tools $ ./android create project --target 24 --name MyFirstApp --path MyFirstApp --activity Main --package com.mrg.myfirstapp
Created project directory: MyFirstApp
....
```

And it makes Helloworld project:

[image]

My OS is linux Mint 15-16bit:

```
$ uname -a
Linux mrg-samsung 3.8.0-19-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 1 16:35:23 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

It's my java version:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

and its my ADT version:

[image]

Comment: Related to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66647 ?

Comment: Yes i think my problem is same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem was because of New version of SDK and ADT so to update ADT please add this address: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
** Be aware it doesn't work with exciting address  begin with http so go to Install New software in ADT and do these steps:
[image]

Then Select this and press Next and Next and accept licence and press finish to download and install:
[image]

Now after restart ADT if you create a project it will work another problem i saw was the AVD doesn't work correctly you can not add new device to solve this problem run this command from SDK path:

```
~/Program/android/adt/sdk/tools $ ./android avd
```

After add your device go to ADT and open AVD from eclipse and press Refresh
[image]

It should work now

Comment: Implemented ur answer & avd is working fine but after then giving this error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22344320/eclipse-error-in-xml-graphical-layout-after-the-new-update & also this error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22344320/eclipse-error-in-xml-graphical-layout-after-the-new-update

Comment: I am in API 21, I did all this but it still created a project with empty src folder

Answer (score 2):

As one guy said

> I had the same problem even though I downloaded the Android SDK and did a clean install, but I just resolved it. I tried to click "Help" -> "Check for updates", and then I got a pop-up message saying everything was up to date, but after further research it appeared to me it wasn't up to date. What you need to do is click "Help" -> "Install new software" and install (this will update it) from this url: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

See here thread https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66647

Comment: Yes i saw this answer and i test and it worked i made a quick guide to this problem

Comment: It worked ! but after then giving this error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22344320/eclipse-error-in-xml-graphical-layout-after-the-new-update & also this error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22344320/eclipse-error-in-xml-graphical-layout-after-the-new-update

Answer (score 0):

Steps to fix:
1. Eclipse go to Help/ Install new software 
2. paste this link. https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
3. I saw two topics "Developer Tools" (5 items) and NDK Plugins (1 Item)
4. Install each item one at at time and restart eclipse
5. After installing the above, Hello World was automatically created with the additional file fragment.

Comment: It worked ! but after then giving this error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22344320/eclipse-error-in-xml-graphical-layout-after-the-new-update & also this error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22344320/eclipse-error-in-xml-graphical-layout-after-the-new-update

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and fixed it.

I changed the version of the Target SDK from API 21 (Android L) to another version.
It just fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but it wouldn't fix because I already had the latest updates. After hours of searches the only way of fixing it was to download a fresh copy of Eclipse and create a new Workspace. Than follow the steps that @minttux has specified. I hope it helps for the newer versions of Eclipse.