# src folder empty on creating new Android project

Tags: android, eclipse

I am creating a new Android application in Eclipse. However on creating the project, **src** folder is empty. There is no package or Activity in **src** folder which I mentioned while creating the project. Also, there is no layout added in **layout** folder. The **manifest** file has no information of Activity.

I also tried importing an existing project, the project gets imported but with empty folders.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adt doesn't create default hello world but command line does](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22203862/adt-doesnt-create-default-hello-world-but-command-line-does)

Comment: try updating your `ADT` and create new `project`

Comment: But after this we have to set preferences as we did earlier. With new ADT bundle we don't have to do so. I had also installed ADT bundle on my MacBook. There was no such issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this

"Help" -> "Install new software" and install (this will update it) from this 
      **url: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/**

```
use https://
don't use http://
```

For any more detail please go through [Adt doesn't create default hello world but command line does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22203862/adt-doesnt-create-default-hello-world-but-command-line-does)

Comment: But after this we have to set preferences as we did earlier. With new ADT bundle we don't have to do so. I had also installed ADT bundle on my MacBook. There was no such issue.

Comment: if you had solved your question then please post answer it'll help other viewer.

Comment: @sur007 It worked ! but after then giving this error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22344320/eclipse-error-in-xml-graphical-layout-after-the-new-update & also this error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22344320/eclipse-error-in-xml-graphical-layout-after-the-new-update

Answer (score 5):

was trying to find answers from several hours...try this...Just changed configuration while creating new project.. click on create empty activity instead of blank activity...You will get hello world xml and java file in src

Comment: This worked like a charm !! But why is this even happening ?? it was all fine before updating.. cant we resolve the root cause ?

Comment: I think this is some bug in new ADT...Previous ADT was fine..Hope they'll fix it soon.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem:
The SRC folder was empty on creation of a new android project. I installed all required updates in the SDK manager.  Additionally, check for new updates and use
`https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/` as the update site (note that this is `https://` and not `http://`).
Restart eclipse and it should work.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @JamesAMohler This is *not* a link-only answer; it's telling you to update via the specified (official, I think) update site but it contains the needed instructions in the post.  As such, it is a real answer.  (I've edited it to make this clearer)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same 'error' and it appears to me if when creating the app I use in the 'application name' non ASCII characters!

Example: čžšćđ...

**So do not use čžšćđ in Application Name!**

And yes, I know it's not good practice to use them in programming.