# android activity_main.xml is missing in tutorial "My First App"

Tags: android, eclipse

I followed exactly what the tutorial described : https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html

But when I clicked "finish", I realized my "src" is empty and  "activity_main.xml" is not existing.

Just wandering what happened? Or Have they changed anything?

The solution is here: 
[src folder empty on creating new Android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22215499/src-folder-empty-on-creating-new-android-project)

"Help" -> "Install new software" and install (this will update it) from this url: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
Thanks
Deryk

Answer (score 2):

I guess , in the second screen of what you are describing **configure the project** you should have unticked `create activity` ,i experimented with same and it mathces with what you have described , for further queries just comment on my answer

Comment: No, I double checked it. "create activity" was checked. It is not the reason.

Comment: Just figure out. The solution is  here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22215499/src-folder-empty-on-creating-new-android-project

Comment: you mean to say ? you figured it out ? or you are asking me to figure out the thing ! seriously dude ! if you don't even know how to install software of latest version ,u think people can know your problem and can help you out?

Comment: What are you talking about? I exactly followed the instructions and it did not work. Now I spent time finding a solution and this solution also helped other people. So if you do not have the knowledge to answer my question, you are welcome to learn a little bit more.

Comment: really ? did you mention what version of eclipse you are having atleast ?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested above the question [src folder empty on creating new Android project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22215499/979998) has the answer.

Whilst updating the ADT may help, I found the answer where they said use **Empty Activity** instead of Blank Activity to fix the immediate problem (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24593781/979998).