# src and layout folder is empty when new application is created

Tags: android, android-layout, src

when i create a new android application project, the src and the layout folder becomes empty and i had installed the latest version of ADT thats 23 and all my sdk's are downloaded and installed. can anyone tell me why does this happen?

Comment: Your question might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22215499/src-folder-empty-on-creating-new-android-project

Answer (score 1):

It took me two days to find a solution. At first my gen folder and src folder were both empty. After re-installing the ADT plugin and creating a new project, my gen folder finally contained everything it needed to, but the src folder was empty. I tried updating the plugin, downloading the sdks again, and etc. To solve all I did was change the activity from blank to empty, and it surprisingly worked. Maybe it's just a bug with the new version, I don't know. This worked for me hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

By default it is empty. Try to add an Activity to the Project. Right click on Project New->Other->Android and choose Android Activity.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. The fix that worked for me was to install the Android Support Library and Android Support Repository from the Android SDK manager.

Go to Android SDK manager and from the Extras , select the above two packages

This link https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html provides more info.

Also while creating the application, I chose empty activity instead of blank activity.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. All you need to do is change your workspace or delete your old workspace and create a new one. I think the problem is your old configuraion at old workspace.
Hope this you help you.