# There is no "res/layout/" folder in my android project (using eclipse, libGDX)

Tags: android, gradle, libgdx

I want to add ads to my aplication via adMob, so I followed this tutorial: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals?hl=de#play

It says:

```
// Lookup your LinearLayout assuming it's been given
// the attribute android:id="@+id/mainLayout".
```

But I have no layouts! Not even a layout folder!

I tried this solution, but it did not work for me: [src folder empty on creating new Android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22215499/src-folder-empty-on-creating-new-android-project)
There was allready everything installed and uninstalling and then installing again also didn't work.

I guess it might have something to do with the gradle-project. I created the project with the gdx-setup tool. But I don't know anything about gradle.

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Just create one. I had this problem with my drawable folder which I manually created and didn't face any problems with my manually created folder.

Comment: Yes, that would be the last option for me, because then I had also to figure out, how the layout xml-files are built up. And I don't know if there maybe is missing something else.

Comment: Here this should help you get started. http://www.dynadream.com/ddweb/index.php/Special_Blog?id=20

Comment: That sounds reasonable! At least I think you brought me back on right way. 

In the Link you posted, they are working with the old adMob-sdk, instead of Google play services, I dont know if this makes any difference.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk libgdx does not use NDK for the layout. It simply creates a GLSurfaceView in Java and sets that as the content view. I would not try using the NDK for this--it will needlessly suck up a lot of your time. Looks like you already found the Google Ads SDK for libgdx tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create a layout folder you can do it all programatically.

Look at our open source libgdx game for an example:

https://github.com/MapleScotDevelopment/LoggerBill

Comment: You are right! I used this Tutorial: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Google-Mobile-Ads-in-Libgdx-%28replaces-deprecated-AdMob%29

But this might be similar, thank you!