# In eclipse activity is not created in manifest

Tags: android

I have a eclipse and updated SDK  but i am unable to understand when i create a new project only src folder is generated.no any default  Activity class is created.Also in manifest only application is loaded activity is not showing.where is the problem.if anyone know whats happening here then please help me.

manifest code is such like that

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
</application>
```

Comment: Try deleting and creating the project all over again

Answer (score 4):

Maybe ur installation wasnt proper. Download it from [here](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html?hl=sk).

**Updated**
As pointed out by Williams it could be a bug since many are facing this problem. So dont worry u r not alone.

Refer to this link below it might help
[Adt doesn't create default hello world but command line does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22203862/adt-doesnt-create-default-hello-world-but-command-line-does)

Comment: This is bug in the new version of ADT

Comment: Really? I just updated few days ago it works fine to me

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66647

Comment: oh well, every tym android does some updates its full of surprises for developers :P

Comment: @Mansoor probably not really a bug, just a misstep since people tend to forget updating their ADT after updating SDK...

Comment: @Andrew T - u r right i am not facing this error/bug though i updated it a couple of days  a ago

Answer (score 0):

Follow this :

File -> new -> android application project.

Then enter the application name correctly and press next.

Then you will see an check-box Create Activity at second position please check it.
That will solve your problem. I hope .

[image: see this for referrence]

Comment: This is bug in the new version of ADT