# Eclipse gives an empty src and assets folder after creating a new android application project

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Eclipse gives an empty src and assets folder after creating a new android application project, I did go help-update and help-install new software, also I tried deleting everything and reinstalling the whole eclipse but it didn't help. Even when I try to manually create a new activity nothing appears in the src folder, even though there is no error message.

Comment: There are some issues with the Android tools update that was published this week. Wait a few days and see if patched updates have been published.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

"Help" -> "Install new software" and install (this will update it) from this url: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

```
use https://
don't use http://
```

For any more detail please go through [Adt doesn't create default hello world but command line does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22203862/adt-doesnt-create-default-hello-world-but-command-line-does)