# Eclipse doesn't create acivity_main in /src automatically

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I have the newest version of Eclipse (32 bits) and I can't create any activity. Even if i make New -> Other -> Android activity it also doesn't make it. I have Windows 8.

Comment: Uninstall and reinstall. Make sure you install ADT plugin.

Comment: What name of activity are you tryin?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190578/adt-will-not-allow-creation-of-android-activity - cannot flag as such as there's no upvoted/accepted answers

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new Android project by default the activity "MainActivity" and layout "activity_main" are created.
the message `activity_main already exists` is displayed.

If you want to add another activity with  `New` -> `Other` -> `Android Activity` you have to change the name :P.

**UPDATE:**

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66647