# Eclipse Android Activity Wizard Not Creating New Activities

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I'm trying to follow the Build Your First App tutorial from the official Android site but I ran into some problem I honestly cannot find solutions to. I can access the Activity Wizard easy enough and I can get as far as here with no trouble:

[image]

But when I press Finish, no `Activity` is created in my project's folders. Anyone know what's going on?

Thanks :)

EDIT: Screenshot of src folder and the rest of my project
[image: I don't have 10 reputation so we're gonna see if this works]

Comment: Maybe add a screenshot of your project structure? Do you have a src folder?

Comment: That's probably a good idea. Added :)

Comment: Try to change "Hierarchical Parent" from com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity to com.example.myfirstapp

Comment: I'm running into the same issue, even re-installed everything, same result, Wizard not creating the activity.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ADT will not allow creation of Android Activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190578/adt-will-not-allow-creation-of-android-activity)

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a bug in the latest (as of Mar 13, 2014) ADT bundle release. An update through Eclipse's *Install New Software* window should fix it. To do this, you can try the following:

1. In Eclipse, go to Help -> Install new software;
2. Pick main update site having the URL `http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse`;
3. In the bottom section **disable "Contact all update sites during install to find required software"**; this causes issues when updating;
4. Check Developer Tools;
5. Perform the rest of the update;

Comment: Ha, just my luck to start learning Android development right as a bug that messes up the tutorial is introduced. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: What to do if already installed ? How can I uninstall this... It crashed when I try to uninstall.... argh Android is such a pain.

Comment: You should try updating the tools you already have. Alternatively, try re-downloading the bundle.