# Eclipse Android wizard not creating new activities

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm trying to create a new android project with Eclipse, but it gives me no activites ..
I have googled it and found that [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22211678/eclipse-android-activity-wizard-not-creating-new-activities)  but even though I tried it many times the problem exists 
it says that the packages are already installed, and it doesn't re-install them and the problem is still there

Comment: why don't you start with android studio and create android project from there ? that would be easy than to download eclipse and all the plugins.

Comment: i already have Eclipse installed and works fine with my previous projects, this error came out of the blue !

Comment: got ADT-plugin?  standard-eclipse shouldnt have pre-build activities

Comment: yes it's already installed and i've done some projects with it, this error came out of the bkue

Comment: After you upgrade the SDK, do you also make a Help/Check for Updates?

Comment: @DerGolem it's up-to-date

Comment: Then, I guess you have to manually add it to the src folder: right click, New/Class ...