# Eclipse android not creating activity

Tags: android, eclipse

I've just tried to get into Android development, but somehow I can't get my project working properly. I followed the "Getting Started" guide (http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html), but I'm stuck on building my project.

Everything is going fine but the creation of my MainActivity. I've left all the settings regarding the activity to default. Somehow when I create my project, there's no activity definition in the AndroidManifest.xml.

I've two potential solutions, but none of them seem to work. The mainly suggested workaround is to update the ADT Plugins through the correct repository ([Eclipse android project not creating blank activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22232836/eclipse-android-project-not-creating-blank-activity?answertab=votes#tab-top)). However in my situation the updater states that I've already got these packages installed.

The other possible solution was to remove the support library from the SDK manager. After that, trying to create a new project in Eclipse should prompt me to install this package. Somehow I don't seem to get this prompt. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/11260656/3786210).

Are there any other possible solutions I could try out to get my project correctly built? Thanks in advance!

*Additional information:*

- Windows 8 (64 bit)
- ADT packages version: 23.0.0.1245622
- Target SDK and Compile With: Android 4.4 (KitKat)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just yse IDEA instead of Eclipse
http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/
Eclipse sometimes can produce such problems

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot. I've got IDEA up and running in just 5 minutes!