# android eclipse not creating blank activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt, eclipse-adt

The problem is, in Eclipse, the `new >> Project >> Android >> Android Application Project >> BlankActivity` does not create any Activities in the `src` directory, and does not include the Activities in the `manifest.xml`.

**I know this question has been asked before:**

1. [Eclipse Juno won't create Android Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11260619/2472266)
2. [Eclipse doesn't create Main Activity and layout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22219392/2472266)
3. [Eclipse android project not creating blank activity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22232836/2472266)

**However**, the selected answers to these all say somthing like:

> click "Help"
>   -> "Install new software" and install (this will update it) from this url: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

**The above answer did not work for  me**. Here are some details of my setup:

1. Installed "Eclipse ADT" from the [Android website](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html)
2. Followed the installation instructions (unzipped contents and opened Eclipse)
3. Downloaded necessary APIs using the ADT Manager
4. Tried creating `new >> Project >> Android >> Android Application Project >> BlankActivity`, this worked fine except no Activity in `src` or `manifest.xml`.
5. Tried the answer given in other SO questions, i.e. "Install new software" and install (this will update it) from this url: `https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/` . **This updated "Development Tools" to version 23.0**.
6. Tried creating `new >> Project >> Android >> Android Application Project >> BlankActivity`, but still did not work.

I know I could install these files manually, but I am following the Android Dev Tutorials and they often assume the base project creation worked perfectly, and do not give the source files.

Comment: `new >> Other >> Android >> Android Application Project`. Refer 
[Creating First Project](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html). Remember, Google is your best friend

Comment: I'm creating projects as you describe, and I am following the direction on the link you give already.

Comment: Check that you are checking all the necessary boxes prior to hitting "Finish"

Comment: The same thing is happening for me. I think it's a bug with the current ADT. You need to select "Empty Activity" instead of "Blank Activity". I think Blank activity was supposed to be removed

Comment: @Gak2 yes, I've been using `EmptyActivity`. It's just that the main tutorials on [Creating First Project](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html) use `BlankActivity`, which includes the `ActionBarActivity`. It's a little frustrating not to be able to follow the official tutorials.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

its currently bugged if you updated to 23.0. see https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72419

Comment: Thanks for the link! Please let me know if you know of a fix for this in the meantime.

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to add, I switched from **Eclipse ADT** to the **Android Studio** and all of the Activity creations work perfectly (i.e. `BlankActivity`, as well as all of the others). It also fixed another bug I was experiencing with the GUI preview in Eclipse.

Comment: I too switched to Android Studio now from Eclipse ADT just today and trying to run the show. But I'm getting "Error:Cause: error in opening zip file". Any Idea, what might have gone wrong ? BTW, I'm in Win7 64 bit OS

Comment: Looks like this "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23828085/android-studio-failed-to-complete-gradle-execution-error-in-opening-zip-file" already has an answer and I'm trying to follow the steps...Will update in SO if it gets resolved and starts working

Comment: Update - Able to run through Android Studio Without any Issues now...Feels better to be in AS than ECLP :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I tried installing the ADT plugin + Eclipse bundle and when I tried their "My First App" example Eclipse would not create an activity.

Manually installing Eclipse first and then adding the latest ADT plugin worked for me.

1. I installed Eclipse Standard 4.4 first (http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/).
2. Then I installed the Android SDK (https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html - use the "GET THE SDK FOR AN EXISTING IDE" link)
3. Then I installed the ADT plugin for Eclipse (https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html)
4. Then I was able to follow their demo project successfully.

Eclipse does automatically create new activities and I can run the application on an actual device.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

I bypassed this issue by creating Empty Activity instead of Blank Activity while creating new android project. Empty Activity provided same code as that of Blank Activity

Comment: This isn't true. `EmptyActivity` comes with no Activities. [**`BlankActivity`**](https://developer.android.com/tools/projects/templates.html#blank-activity) creates a main `Activity` that includes an `ActionBar`, `Menu`, basic layout, and has options to include a navigation type and use `Fragments`. Also, It's not just `BlankActivity` that doesn't work, it's everything except `EmptyActivity`.

Comment: the solution I have provided is for BlankActivity not creating activtity issue in my case (Eclipse kepler with ADT 23).Creating a EmptyActivity created an activity and thereafter src folder contained that activity.I am not referring to other aspects of this issue.