# SRC folder in Eclipse is empty (MainActivity class not created) after creating a new android project using Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, class, src

SRC folder in Eclipse is empty (MainActivity class not created) after creating a new android project using Eclipse-

I created a new android project using Eclipse. But I am seeing SRC folder is empty in the project explorer. But as per my understanding it should create few .java files automatically like MainActivity.java.

Comment: Is it new Eclipse & SDK ?

Comment: while creating a new android project it will ask for the mainactivity to be created or not[with check box]. Try it one more time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ADT will not allow creation of Android Activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190578/adt-will-not-allow-creation-of-android-activity)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190578/adt-will-not-allow-creation-of-android-activity  got solution from above link...  This s the solution Okay, this worked for me: "Help" -> "Install new software" and install (this will update it) from this url: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ I guess the Android website doesn't have an up-to-date version of ADT? Not sure where you're supposed to download the latest version from. –  NewShelbyWoo

Answer (score 19):

I had this problem for the longest time. When creating the android application, use "empty activity" instead of "blank" activity. Fixed the problem for me immediately.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: well...its a easy solution!

Answer (score 10):

Go to following: 
*'Help'->'Install New Software'* and type 
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Select ADT option and install it.
It will update the ADT.

Even I had the same problem and my issue got resolved with it!!

Answer (score 0):

After entering the Application Name, Project name, etc in the **New Android Application** window, the next window shown is this :[image]

Make sure you check the **Create Activity** checkbox, otherwise the activity will not be created by default.

You still can create an activity by right-clicking on the project and     **New > Other > Android > Android Activity**. But you have to make sure you check the **Launcher Activity** checkbox in case it is the first activity of your application

Comment: I have tried both methods outlined, the one of Creating a project from scratch and New > Other > Android > Android Activity, still nothing. How can I alleviate this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps someone :)

I had the same 'error' and it appears to me if when creating the app I use in the 'application name' non ASCII characters !

Example: čžšćđ...

**So do NOT USE čžšćđ in Application Name !!!**

`and yes I know it's not good practice to use them in programing :D`