# Every time I create a new Android Project, src folder and is empty as well as the layout folder

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I'm using Eclipse IDE which I downloaded from Google.

I do choose the option to create a main activity, and I choose a custom name. But those folders end up being blank upon creation for some reason.

How do I fix this?

Note: This is the first time this has happened. I have two previous projects, and they are fine.

Comment: Have you tried re-downloading the Bundle from android's site ?

Comment: No I haven't. I didn't think of it. I'll do it right now.

Comment: Exact same problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22243651/src-folder-in-eclipse-is-empty-mainactivity-class-not-created-after-creating-a

Comment: Here is my answer to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22310978/2802705 .. Hope this helps!!