# Eclipse create new android application project activity_main.xml file missing from layout folder

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I am following the tutorial here: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html and when I create the android application project it says there should be a hello world program already inside it. I checked the myApp>res>layout folder and the activity_main.xml file is missing. I have already checked on udemy and many people are having this problem as well and I cannot find the answer. Any help would be appreciated as I am new to this website and programming and app development in general. :)

I am running SDK 23 and and ADT 23. I have visited this thread: [Eclipse doesn't generate MainActivity.java & activity_main.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22278479/eclipse-doesnt-generate-mainactivity-java-activity-main-xml) and have not found a solution. Any help will be appreciated.

edit: I noticed I am also missing my src code. When watching tutorial videos this code is pre-generated. My src file is empty.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SRC folder in eclipse is empty (MainActivity class not created) after creating a new android project using eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22243651/src-folder-in-eclipse-is-empty-mainactivity-class-not-created-after-creating-a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution : 
I have been struggling with this issue for 2 days now. Searched through countless posts and countless suggestions.

With the new ADT kit I was selecting "Blank Activity"

This morning I tried "Empty Activity"

This creates the Main activity

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly. Strange how they changed what activity to pick without mentioning it in the google documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and tried a lot of things to recover it, but it doesn't want to work until now. It looks like it's a known issue.
For more information search for issue-nr 72603 on https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list.

Andy

Comment: Thanks for replying. I just downloaded Android Studio. It's in beta but at least it works.