# Eclipse not creating new Activity and xml layout file (issues started after updating eclipse and sdk)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt, eclipse-adt

Today I have update Android SDK tools & eclipse. Current SDK tools 24.0.1, Android development Tools 23.0.4.1468518, eclipse version 4.4.1. After update SDK & eclipse I create new project. In this project src folder is empty & res/layout folder also empty,  activity & xml files are not creating. I have to manually create it.

I seen my answers like [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22243651/src-folder-in-eclipse-is-empty-mainactivity-class-not-created-after-creating-a), [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22215499/src-folder-empty-on-creating-new-android-project) etc.

Answer like:-  "
    Try this
    "Help" -> "Install new software" and install (this will update it) from this url: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/"

But I have already update it.But not solve my problem. So, How to create activity & xml automatically?

Comment: Please try updating to SDK tools 24.0.2 (see my answer below).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Latest

As I already said that `ADT 23.0.4` and `SDK 24.0.1` are not compatible to each other.

We have got another update to of `Android SDK` to `24.0.2` (May be their team read our this question and released an update so quickly). However this update **has not been** documented yet on [this page](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/tools-notes.html) but still you will be able to see it in your `Eclipse's SDK Manager`.

I updated my SDK to `24.0.2` and now it is working fine. You too can try to update your `Android SDK` to `24.0.2` and hopefully everything will work fine.

### Older Answer

The `ADT Plugin for Eclipse` and `Android SDK` both should be compatible to each other for making Eclipse do such things automatically.

But it seems like `ADT 23.0.4 (Released in October 2014)` and `SDK Tools, Revision 24.0.1 (Released in December 2014)` are not compatible to each other.

We should expect an update to ADT plugin soon which will be compatible with SDK tools 24.0.1.

You can check from the documentation:

> For SDK Tools, Revision 23.0.4 (October 2014) they have mentioned the following points.
>
> Android SDK Platform-tools revision 19 or later.
>
> *If you are developing in Eclipse with ADT, note that this version of SDK Tools is designed for use with ADT 23.0.4 and later.*

If you notice,

> But for SDK Tools, Revision 24.0.0 & 24.0.1 (December 2014), They have only mentioned
>
> Android SDK Platform-tools revision 19 or later.

And if you check [this document](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/tools-notes.html) then you will find for SDK 23 or earlier with each revision the compatible ADT version was mentioned but only with 24 they have not mentioned anything yet. So the compatible version is yet to come.

I had same issue but in the end had to undo my update to SDK tool to back to 23.0.4.

If you want to undo your update you can follow the following simple steps:

1. Download the older ADT plugin manually.
2. Extract the contents and copy the `tools` folder from there.
3. Go to your `SDK installation directory` and replace the `tools` folder.

Your SDK will be back to 23 version and everything will start working again.

Comment: Latest update of Android SDK Tools it's working now. Thank you @GPRathour

Comment: https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/119386/ seems to be the relevant change in 24.0.2 - it includes a snapshot of old 23.x templates while android studio gets independent new templates. I guess that also means that one should prefer to use studio to create projects from templates since the eclipse ones are stuck with what we have today.

Answer (score 2):

Try running your Android SDK Manager again, install any available updates for the Tools category and after that select `Help > Check for Updates` from the Eclipse menu (installing any detected updates here too which should then restart Eclipse).

I was getting the same problem before and it started working again after I have Android SDK Tools version **24.0.2** installed after the above process.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: when creating a new android application use "Empty Activity" instead of "Blank Activity".

This will fix the problem immediately.

Comment: I dont understand why someone down voted this answer. Isn't it better to leave a comment stating why you are down voting any answer?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you have to reinstall eclipse after it crashes. That's why it is a good idea they made it portable. But you can try to go back from the about eclipse uninstall component. But in my experience if you blew the ini and all that maybe the fastest way is to reinstall especially when there are so many dependencies like in adt.

You can also install regular eclipse and android plugin you don't have to use only adt. And maybe eclipse is more stable like that

Another thing you need to recompile the project probably