# Src empty, MainActivity doesn't generate

Tags: java, android, eclipse, main-activity

Then i have installed all file of SDK and i have created the New Android Application Project, I saw the src is empty, so there wasn't the MainActivity and a lot of file like the apk or ActivityMain.
I cleaned a lot of time the project and "Build automatically" is flagged.
Eclipse doesn't "run" the apk because there isn't...
Anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190578/adt-will-not-allow-creation-of-android-activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have unchecked the "Create activity" box in the New Android Application Project wizard. To generate a new `Activity`, right click the project and press *"New" -> "Other" -> Expand "Android" -> "Android Activity"*. Now a wizard for creating an `Activity` should appear.

Whenever you build your project after that, an .apk file should be created.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It work, but Do you know how to start it automatically?

Comment: How do you start **what** automatically? If you mean to run the .apk on an Android-device, you just right-click your project and hover on "Run As" -> "Android application". In the new window should be able to chose what device to run the application on.

Comment: I'm sorry I have not explained well... I'd like the mainactivity genereted automatically, not I have to manually create it.

Comment: Then you just check the "Create activity" when you create a new project from _"New" -> "Android Application Project"_.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating. 

Click "Help" -> "Install new software" and install from https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

I had the same issue before. It seems that the version I downloaded was not up to date.

Comment: No problem. Have you tried just downloading and installing the eclipse/adt bundle?

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this problem, but i figured out. I choosed `Empty Activity` in step 6 instead of `Blank Activity`, rest of steps are same as yours.

```
1. New Android Application Project 
2. Selected API 19 4.4 KitKat for Minimum, target and compile with SDK. 
3. Theme Holo Light 
4. Uncheck create custom launcher 
5. Make sure create activity IS checked, everything else left alone 
6. Create activity checked on next screen and selected Empty Activity 
7. Activity Name and Layout Name left as defaults. 
8. Click finish..
```

I hope this will work for you too.