# Eclipse unable to load project properly in android?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, eclipse-plugin

I have just updated my **SDK**. But here i am getting trouble with my new sdk. What i am facing is that, when i create a new project **main.xml** & **Main.java** file not created automatically, I have to create it manually. I have seen many solution but it's not working for me. So my question is that how can i resolve from this problem?

[image: Problem]

**Edited**

I have solve above problem. But now i am getting new trouble. When i create a new Project It's create **appcompact_v7** automatically. How to fix this problem?

Comment: you may have to update you IDE plugin

Comment: I have already update it. but still not working. @AndroidGeek

Comment: did you restart your eclipse?

Comment: many times restart my eclipse. but same problem facing. @AndroidGeek

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190578/adt-will-not-allow-creation-of-android-activity

Answer (score 0):

Did you want create an android project?

So, when you want create activity project in eclipse you should select **"Blank Activity"**.. that is step three in create an android project.