# Eclipse fails to generate necessary Android files

Tags: java, android, eclipse, wizard

I have a problem with Eclipse. It is the first time that I have this problem and can't solve it from a couple of days.
When I start a new Android project in Eclipse. It's run but when the wizard ends, the `MainActivity.java` file and the `activity_main.xml` file of the project are not there. I have deleted the old Eclipse folder and created a new folder but always there is this problem. Does anyone know why this is? Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190578/adt-will-not-allow-creation-of-android-activity

Comment: See if you can load the files manually after creating your project.

Answer (score 0):

Help > Check for Updates
If updates are found, proceed through the install wizard and click Finish at the end
This worked for me the other day

Answer (score -1):

Although this isn't a direct answer to your question, I would recommend using AndroidStudio, haven't had any such issues in it.

I would also venture to guess that it appears as though you are breezing through the wizard and probably not checking the boxes that would automatically create such files.