# Creating new Android application project creating src directory with out any activity

Tags: android, adt

when i'm trying to create new application project using Adt it is behaving like this,till yesterday it worked fine.Can some one help me in finding out why it is behaving like this?

when i compared with my friend adt Android sdk manager 
his adt showing api-19 rev 2 but in mine it is api-19 rev 3

and i have followed steps suggested in [ADT will not allow creation of Android Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190578/adt-will-not-allow-creation-of-android-activity)
after installing i have restarted adt even then facing same problem.

Comment: Have you updated ADT ?

Comment: i havn't manually updated anything

Comment: Because , many users are reporting same this error search on SO first, please.

Comment: Update both your SDK and ADT first, then reconfirm your issue.

Comment: @Andrew T if he will update his adt to 22.6 of google latest release then he will face many problem like it does not create avd from AVD manager so suggest him to upgrade him to ADT 22.3 it is stable and work fine

Comment: Re-installing Adt worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Just go like this **Right click on the folder you want it on your project and select New->Class** and then input the name in the form you see....