# Android SDK 22.6 Malfunctions

Tags: android

In the new updated SDK, verison 22.6, there are few bugs.
Once the SDK has been updated, while creating a new project, there won't be the default main Activity class and the xml too..
It's been a few days since the update has been done. So far nothing has been done to fix it.
What's happening with the SDK developers. Such kinda malfunction happened when they released SDK verion 22.2.
Fix it fast. Else any alternative?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ADT will not allow creation of Android Activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190578/adt-will-not-allow-creation-of-android-activity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now the problem has been fixed with the upgraded release of ADT 22.6.1

Answer (score 1):

Do this:
"Help" -> "Install new software" and install (this will update it) from this url: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
This should help resolve the issue