# Android Hello world Not generated Class

Tags: android, class

i have the problem, when i created a Android application it not generated class and layoout file.
i have read the explanation [Hello Wordl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190578/adt-will-not-allow-creation-of-android-activity)

but i got the message:
Cannot complete the request. See the error log for details. "Android DDMS" will be ignored because it is already installed. "Android Development Tools" will be ignored because it is already installed. "Android Hierarchy Viewer" will be ignored because it is already installed. "Android Native Development Tools" will be ignored because it is already installed. "Android Traceview" will be ignored because it is already installed. "Tracer for OpenGL ES" will be ignored because it is already installed.

i look at [uninstall plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190076/cannot-create-or-edit-android-virtual-devices-avd-from-eclipse-adt-22-6/22198007#22198007) but the button uninstall is disable.

any idea ?

Comment: Are you trying to install these tools. Coz it looks like you already have them.

Comment: This seems to be a common error with the latest ADT, it doesn't seem to generate classes properly. I'd recommend using the example I provided here as an initial setup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23653778/nullpointerexception-accessing-views-in-oncreate/24527530#24527530

Answer (score 0):

Answering based on the tutorial you linked: creating Empty Activity instead of Blank Activity generates both application class and layout file.