# Cannot create AVD - Eclipse, MAC OSX, Android 4.4.2

Tags: java, android, eclipse, macos, android-virtual-device

I cannot create a new AVD in Eclipse on MAC OSX for testing.

Situation:

- I have installed System Images for Android 4.4.2.
- I have checked for update under "Help".
- I have checked the location for android SDK.
- I have installed older versions of Android with related system images.

When I try to create it just waits, when I click "OK". Nothing happens - even if I wait for minutes.

Any suggestions?!

[image]

Comment: Try setting a valid size for the SD card.  I've seen issues in the past with the AVD Manager not playing nice if there is no SD card size or one that is less than about 512MB.

Comment: I have tried that. It still doesn't create an AVD.

Comment: Sorry, can't say that I've seen this exact problem before.  Just did an update of my entire SDK on the Mac (SDK Tools 22.6, Platform-tools 19.0.1, Build tools 19.0.3) and was able to create a 4.4.2 Google x86 AVD without a problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot create or edit Android Virtual Devices from Eclipse (OK button "WORKS")](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190076/cannot-create-or-edit-android-virtual-devices-from-eclipse-ok-button-works)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a strange issue that I just encountered as well, here is my solution:

**1) Start avd from command line:**

*1.1. Open Terminal*

*1.2. Use the `cd` command to navigate to the tools folder in the android SDK*

--> `cd <Path to Android SDK>/tools`

*1.3. type `./android avd`*

**2) Create a new device in the device manager that just opened up**

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem on MAC OSX, SDK 22.6, unable to create a new device up to 4.0

My answer is inspired from here:

[Cannot create or edit Android Virtual Devices (AVD) from Eclipse, ADT 22.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190076/cannot-create-or-edit-android-virtual-devices-avd-from-eclipse-adt-22-6)
and
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66661
and 
[Eclipse can't create new AVD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22287058/eclipse-cant-create-new-avd)

I proceed like this: 
(1) launch avd from commandLine : ***android avd***
(2) Choose device definition then clone a new devices: e.g ***Galaxy nexus by google***
(3) Create a new device from the cloned device and set as ***target API 4.4.2***, then 
(4) set the SD card size to ***1000MiB***, Click OK
(5) Finally start the Emulator.

I tested, and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Run AVD manager from terminal and then create AVD.
To do this, cd to android sdk tools folder and run AVD manager with following command:

```
android avd
```

Answer (score 0):

U can try create using AVDManager.exe on your android folder, not from inside eclipse.