# Eclipse can't create new AVD

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

Trying to create a new AVD specifically for Android 2.3.3 Gingerbread.

I've cloned a device based on the 3.7" FWVGA slider as indicated by this image

[image]

This shows up in the "Device Definitions" tab

[image]

When I get to the "Create new Android Virtual Device (AVD)" window, I believe I have properly filled in the form as shown here

[image]

However, when I go to click "OK", which is a live button and not grayed out, there is no response at all from Eclipse. The application doesn't freeze or anything it just does not allow me to finish creating the new AVD. These specs were as indicated by my class but any advice that could help rectify the situation would be greatly appreciated while I await a response from my professor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a bug in 22.6. We're preparing a 22.6.1 update that will fix this.

I think you can use the standalone AVD Manager, running `tools/android avd` from a shell to create one.

Comment: I appreciate the response. I will try this.

Comment: 22.6 broke stuff... I've been fighting Eclipse/ADT on my Linux/Mac and Windows machine since Saturday. Has anyone heard an ETA on the patch?  All that said--I was able to run the AVD Manager standalone and create a new AVD; thank you, @Xavier.