# Can't create new AVD (No response)

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, emulation, android-virtual-device

My AVD configuration is as follows:

- Device: `Nexus 4`
- Target: `Android 4.0 - API Level 14`
- CPU/ABI: `ARM(armeabi-v7a)`
- Skin: `Skin with dynamic hardware controls`
- Memory Option: RAM: `1907` VM Heap: `64`
- Internal Storage: `200 MiB`
- SD Card: `500 MiB`

I clicked the `OK` button, but there was no response.

SDK directory: `D:\Android\android-sdk-windows`
AVD located at `D:\Android\android-sdk-windows\.android\avd`

I installed complete packages and tried to change the target, but it still failed. I also referenced other similar problems, but they didn't help.

Thanks in advance for helping me.

Comment: `Memory Option:Ram:1907 VM Heap:64`. try decreasing your RAM < 768 MB

Comment: While this is not a perfect solution, but try this. Close your project, open your sdk folder, execute Avd Manager from there.

Answer (score 3):

Try go to your android sdk folder and right click menu "AVD Manager.exe" and choose menu "Run as administrator" and try create it again.

I found this problem too after update android adk on Windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Using AVD in your eclipse development environment I would like to suggest use 
[Android x86](http://www.android-x86.org/) or a better one [Genymotion](http://genymotion.com) Virtual Devices

In you current settings Your value for RAM is more

```
Ram:1907 VM Heap:64
```

> RAM 1907 is not supported by AVD

```
Value should be less than 768MB
```

Note: AVD is generally very slower than the Android x86 or Genymotion(earlier known as AndroVM)

Answer (score 0):

That may be the same issue seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190076/cannot-create-or-edit-android-virtual-devices-from-eclipse-ok-button-works).
Basically after updating to ADT 22.6, AVD manager from inside eclipse stopped working correctly, but if you launch it manually it works.