# Can't create AVD or test any application with AVD after update build tools to 22.6

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, build-tools

After update `SDK-Build-Tools` to `22.6` and `ADT-Plugin` can't create AVD or launch any application via any emulator those which were previously created before updating.There was no error message has shown in `console` or in `log-cat`.So can't track the issue.

Here is the Screen shot. After clicking on OK button nothing happened.

> [image]

Comment: Two Ways : (1) restart abd, restart eclipse ,If this doesnt work then (2) close the eclipse and go to your sdk folder, run AVD Manager from there and create new AVD from there.

Comment: @Kedarnath : i have already done that. From tomorrow i m trying with no success :(

Comment: This seems to be new problem, lots of users are posting same question.

Comment: API 10 is very buggy with AVDs.  Set the RAM to 768.  Even though it isn't realistic, the AVD needs it.  Oh, and use the Intel Atom x86.

Comment: I just updated to 22.6 and started my Nexus S API 10 AVD with 768 RAM and the Intel Atom image successfully.

Comment: @RickFalck : i have tried as u suggested but nothing happened

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot create or edit Android Virtual Devices (AVD) from Eclipse, ADT 22.6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190076/cannot-create-or-edit-android-virtual-devices-avd-from-eclipse-adt-22-6)

Comment: @Rick Falck: I tried with 22.6 and had the same problem.

Comment: @RobH : u can visit that link laalto provided

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known issue, we'll have an update out with the fix shortly.

Comment: Thank you for answer, Otherwise we were thinking it is problem at ourside.

Comment: Lots of users are facing this problem. Please do update your answer whenever you solve this issue.

Comment: Until this issue is fixed, can anyone recommend a site where an older version that works is available for download?

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid doing all the reverting to older versions by using the command line;

For unix systems:

```
android list targets
```

Will list the available api targets you have

```
 android create avd -n <name> -t <targetID> [-<option> <value>] ...
```

Will create the avd, then you should be able to see the AVD in your AVD Manager in eclipse. You can check the documentation at http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds-cmdline.html

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately in the latest SDK, Emulator isn't working that way. It's still a bug.

But don't worry. There is an alternative way to do it.
To start the emulator:
Go to Window-> Android SDK Manager-> Tools-> Manage AVDs 
Then select any AVD of your choice and click start.

[image: SDK Manager]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Please comment for further questions.

Comment: this is not the solution

Answer (score 0):

If "Create Virtual Device" button in Android Studio UI is not working, there is probably an Android SDK or other parts missing, there is no popup showing it, but if you just installed AS, or cleared all SDK files, do the next thing:

`File-Settings-Language & Frameworks-Android SDK-SDK Platforms`, install SDK, add `Android SDK Command-line Tools` in `SDK Tools` tab.

And do not forget to add path to `Project Structure`