# I cant create an Android Virtual Device

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, android-virtual-device

I tried to create a AVD but when I click Ok Button nothing happens

Here a picture

> [image]

And here my SDK

> [image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22216119/3330969

Comment: There is no meaning to downvote this question, since this is a new bug of Android.

Comment: So, No solution? maybe install an old SDK?

Comment: If you have backup of old SDK then for right now its best to work with it.

Comment: Wich SDK you recommend?? to download it? THX

Comment: Opps, If you dont have backup then I dont think it is possible to download previous version.

Comment: Okkk man, i am in troubles!!!

Comment: You may found old working SDK from your friends. SDK size is in GBs so I cant send you by email, Otherwise I would surely send mine working version.

Comment: You welcome,I am sure update will come soon at lots of developer getting this same error. Till the time you can work with real device rather than AVD :)

Comment: @MarceloAlarcon from images I can see you not click any option. Select snapshot option and try. Hope its work.