# new AVD can't click on OK button, not system image

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I have installed the android sdk 2.2, 4.2, 4.1.2 and the system images as well.

However, I can't click on the OK button. It is visible, but when I click on it nothing happens.

And I can't add an image, cause don't have 10 reputations, so uploaded the image here:

> [image]

Comment: Check this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190076/cannot-create-or-edit-android-virtual-devices-from-eclipse-ok-button-works/22190150#22190150

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22215958/3330969