# Can not create New AVD in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, emulation, android-virtual-device

I installed android eclipse on a new machine. I am not able to create a new AVD. The new AVD does not show up after I enter all details to create a new AVD and click OK. For your reference I am attaching create Avd window and updated sdk window. Please help to fix this issue.

Comment: Its new Issue. http://stackoverflow.com/q/22215958/3330969

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66661

Comment: Thanks Kedaranath. I thought It was my mistake no configure eclipse on my machine.

Comment: You welcome. Lots of users getting this issue. Lets hope to get it solved soon.

Comment: Yes,I am also waiting anyway thanks

Answer (score 1):

Per the issue you linked the wporkaround is:

Thanks for both details. I have enough details to solve the AVD Manager issue now.
Note that the emulator not finishing booting is a different issue.

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/sdklib/repository/descriptors/IdDisplay

That means somehow the sdklib bundled with ADT doesn't match the one from Tools 22.6
(the SDK Manager is external but the AVD Manager is still bundled in ADT)

WORKAROUND: In Eclipse, open the SDK Manager (via toolbar or Window menu) > Tools > Manager AVDs.
This will invoke the external version of the AVD Manager which will properly generate AVDs.
Other workaround: use the command-line version (Shell or cmd.exe, cd SDK, "tools\android.bat avd").

I'll get a fix out ASAP.

Comment: does not work when i open AVD Manager via eclipse but does work via cmd, thanks!