# Cannot create emulater in AVD

Tags: android, eclipse

I downloaded SDK 'ARM EABI v7a System Image'and tried to create emulater(Nexus 4) as shown in below url

> [image]
>   [image]

but OK button is not responding. I restarted my system after installing 'ARM EABI v7a System Image'. Can any one help me ?

Comment: May be this problem http://stackoverflow.com/q/22215958/3330969

Comment: This is a bug which will be fixed in the next update. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66661

Comment: try restart your eclipse and try again.

Comment: hi wqrahd, i restated eclipse 3 time and tried but dose't work.

Comment: @Shiva, Its not your fault.

Comment: You can run AVD Manager.exe from outside Eclipse. Click on it in Windows file explorer. This will let you create an AVD. (It does say this in the 66661 bug thread.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot create or edit Android Virtual Devices (AVD) from Eclipse, ADT 22.6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190076/cannot-create-or-edit-android-virtual-devices-avd-from-eclipse-adt-22-6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I have not found solution how to make it work in IDE. But AVD works for me when I start it using command line.

To start it from command line go to your sdk/tools folder and run the next command

```
android avd
```