# Give an error when create AVD in eclipse JUNO

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I am using windows XP and eclipse JUNO version for android programming and i have latest SDK  and ADT 22.6.0 and set to the eclipse setting. But when i create new AVD from AVD Manager and fill the right detail and then press ok button then nothing happen and in error log its give below error so please give me suggestion for that.
If i attach device then android program run perfectly.

**Error:**

**Title** : Event detail
**Message**: Unhandled event loop exception

**Exception stack trace**:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/sdklib/repository/descriptors/IdDisplay
    at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.widgets.AvdCreationDialog.validatePage(AvdCreationDialog.java:1027)
    at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.widgets.AvdCreationDialog.access$400(AvdCreationDialog.java:85)
    at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.widgets.AvdCreationDialog$3.widgetSelected(AvdCreationDialog.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
    at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.widgets.AvdSelector.onNew(AvdSelector.java:898)
    at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.widgets.AvdSelector.access$100(AvdSelector.java:84)
    at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.widgets.AvdSelector$2.widgetSelected(AvdSelector.java:272)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:916)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is ADT bug. So you have to create AVD starting AVD manager using command line.

Check my answer for similar question [Cannot create emulater in AVD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22295134/cannot-create-emulater-in-avd/22296632#22296632).

Comment: Thanks @ Sergey Pekar. When i did it its open AVD Manager and i create one avd and open it, its run perfectly but from the eclipse if i do same thing then its not happen and give error as described above.

Answer (score 0):

Use this emulator instead http://www.genymotion.com/ you must build the app to run it but it is faster and will work on WinXP (Eclipse AVD Emulator will probably just run wayyyyyy too slow even if you open it).