# Eclipse is not working properly after update it

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have just updated my SDK. After the update, my eclipse does not work properly.
I am facing two problems.

1. When I create a new project, it adds the **appcompat_v7** library project automatically. I have seen many solutions, and I understand why it's being added automatically. But every time I create a new project,  it adds **appcompact_v7**. How do I fix this problem so that the file **appcompact_v7** should only be added the first time ,not every time I create a new project?
2. Whenever I try to create a new emulator it seems like it doesn't work. (Nothing happening when I click on the **OK**-button at the bottom of the window)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22216119/3330969

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't create AVD or test any application with AVD after update build tools to 22.6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22215958/cant-create-avd-or-test-any-application-with-avd-after-update-build-tools-to-22)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot create or edit Android Virtual Devices (AVD) from Eclipse, ADT 22.6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190076/cannot-create-or-edit-android-virtual-devices-avd-from-eclipse-adt-22-6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately in the latest SDK, Emulator isn't working that way. It's still a bug.

But don't worry. There is an alternative way to do it.

To start the emulator:
Go to Window-> Android SDK Manager-> Tools-> Manage AVDs 
Then select any AVD of your choice and click start.

[image: SDK Manager]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

For your 1st problem:

You'll have to back off **Android SDK Tools to Rev. 22.3 and Android SDK Platform-tools to 19**.
Please comment for further questions.

Comment: Thank you @Suraj. but i facing 1st problem continuously. appcompat_v7 add when create new project. i want to only one time create not every time. see my 1st problem in my question.