# Android 22.6 issue

Tags: android, api, sdk, adt

Why am I not able to create any projects with Android API version 2.3.3 ? I have a fully updated ADT-Plugin 22.6 version. I am aware of the problems regarding some developers having no activity creation issues, but here it doesn't allow me to fully complete creation of my project at 2.3.3. It says 14 should be the min API level. Thanks in advance..

Followed [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190578/adt-will-not-allow-creation-of-android-activity#) for installing the plugin

Comment: Please check this link https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66661

Comment: Thanks Kedarnath...but these issues are really troublesome..avd creation isnt been allowed..all api's reload after every cleaning or saving of proj..

Comment: SDK Developers are working on it, see the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/22216119/3330969

Comment: the introduction of new fragment layout in 22.6 probably could be the reason i am not able to make a proj in API 2.3.3..but still fragments start from API level 11..then why the restriction 14??