# Unable to create Android Virtual Device in eclipse, (Ok button is clicked but no action performed)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am new to android app developing, I am trying to run my android application in AVD available in eclipse but the thing is I'm unable to create a new AVD.
(Previously a AVD was there in eclipse but it was not worked as fast, so i deleted that)

Its possible to fill all the necessary fields given for creating a new AVD, finally when OK button is clicked there is no action performed in eclipse IDE.

Can anyone know whats exactly blocking me from creating a new AVD. Here is my screenshot.

[image: Android virtual device]

Comment: this a known bug will be fixed in the next update bug is filed already

Comment: also, as a side note, please check the "Use host GPU" checkBox.. improves the speed of your emulator

Comment: @Arun, Its new well known bug, Please check this [link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66661) , [Google developers are already working to solve it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22215958/3330969)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot create or edit Android Virtual Devices (AVD) from Eclipse, ADT 22.6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190076/cannot-create-or-edit-android-virtual-devices-avd-from-eclipse-adt-22-6)

Comment: In case this is useful to anyone: give it a couple of minutes at least to complete. I thought it was a bug and found this page but it actually worked after that time with no indication it was doing anything. Also note that the avds are linked to a user as I found trying to run avd as root.

Answer (score 3):

I was also facing trouble to create AVD on my eclipse. Although my real device Galaxy S3 is working nicely as online AVD. I needed to download & install the correct driver for that and it started to do the job. But I am still searching for the real reason of the problem creating the virtual one. But here is the cofig, what is working for me now, after a long time trying.

After facing problem, first of all I installed all the package file including the Intel X86 Atom System Image for my required Android Version(For me it's Android 4.3 API 18). So that I can select the Intel Atom x86 as the CPU/ABI while creating the AVD.[image: SELECT THE RIGHT PACKAGES]

And don't forget to install the Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator(HAXM) installer under the Extras on Android SDK Manager.[image: intel x86]

Here, what was my config for the AVD

1. Device=Nexus 7 (7.02)
2. Target=Android 4.3
3. CPU/ABI=Intel Atom (x86)
4. SKIN=HVGA
5. RAM=2048
6. HEAP=64
7. Internal Storage=2000
8. External=2000
9. Emulation Options=Tick on "Use Host GPU"

And please keep patience, as it will take a while to start the AVD.[image]