# Why does my AVD emulator not show up?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, emulation, android-virtual-device

I tried to setup my workplace to work on Android apps, but after two days still with no luck.
I downloaded Android SDK bundle, that includes Android SDK, Eclipse and AVD manager, installed and updated everything.

I created a virtual device with AVD, that's how it looks and it seems right, but for sake of pecision I also say I tried a lot of configurations trying to combine the various voices.

- DEVICE: **Galaxy Nexus (4.65'' 720 x 1280)**
- TARGET: **Android 4.3**
- Hardware Keyboard Present: **[V]**
- Display a skin with hardware controls: **[V]**
- RAM: **512 MB**
- VM HEAP: **64 MB**
- SD STORAGE: **512 MB**

Emulation options: **Snapshot[ok] Host GPU [no]**
I click on start and then Ok.

When in cmd I try to launch *adb devices* it returns an empty list; Eclipse, in the devices tab shows nothing. I also tried to cmd :

- **adb kill-server**
- **adb start-server**

with no luck.

By the way I tried to create an Android 4.3 sample project, notepad.
When I click on debug it opens AVD window asking me which device I choose to debug the application.

I choose the device I created, it loads for a while and the eclipse console shows an *ok* as if all went good. The problem is no window appears; I don't know in which of the above steps  the device emulator window should appear, but it never does.

Any hint?

Comment: Its new well known bug, Please check this [link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66661) , [Google developers are already working to solve it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22215958/3330969)

Comment: That's not my problem. The creation of the device, as I click on Ok, goes on with no problem, and the device is shown (in AVD only) with the green mark in the side. Even if I start it it correctly loads resources and it seems everything is fine, but the virtual device is never shown in the screen.

Comment: How many GB RAM you have ?

Comment: 4GB, I think it's not a matter of time, yesterday I launched the emulator and I returned in the room about an hour later, with no luck.

Comment: Still looking for a solution!

Comment: Did you try restarting pc ?

Comment: Of course I did, I'm fighting with it since yesterday. It's becoming frustrating.