# New Update of Eclipse Doesn't allow to create AVD even pressed ok?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have updated my eclipse and now when I try to create a new AVD , Even when I press ok, nothing happens.
As you can see ,my AVD shows repairable devices. But when clicked repair, nothing happens.

[image]

ANd When I try to create a new AVD Even after clicking OK nothing happens.
As you can see, ok is clickable. But when clicked nothing happens.

[image]

I have installed all the files through SDK manager under each version. 
Any solution?

Comment: ¿Are you executing Eclipse as Admin? could be a permission problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot create or edit Android Virtual Devices (AVD) from Eclipse, ADT 22.6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190076/cannot-create-or-edit-android-virtual-devices-avd-from-eclipse-adt-22-6)

Answer (score 0):

As many posts say this is a bug related to the new version of ADT, I did not want to rollback and test/use a different version. For me it worked by going directly in the Android SDK folder and launching the AVD manager (AVD Manager.exe) or from SDK manager -> Tools -> Manage AVDs. Meanwhile will wait for a fix related to the ADT plugin.