# AVD - Unable to create Device

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I'm not able to create a new AVD. After entering the information in the controls and clicking `OK` does nothing. The dialog just sits there, no error messages no nothing.

I am using latest eclipse 64 bits for java developers (kepler, downloaded today), installed ADT plugin manually (following instructions developer.google.com):

The create new AVD screen:
[image]

The SDK setup:
[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated. I'm using JDK 1.7 (minor version is 40 I think).

Comment: @Raghunandan That was it, found the workaround too on that page: WORKAROUND: In Eclipse, open the SDK Manager (via toolbar or Window menu) > Tools > Manager AVDs.
This will invoke the external version of the AVD Manager which will properly generate AVDs.
Other workaround: use the command-line version (Shell or cmd.exe, cd SDK, "tools\android.bat avd").

Comment: @Raghunandan If you change your comment to answer, I'll accept it. Thank you.

Comment: added both as an answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot create or edit Android Virtual Devices (AVD) from Eclipse, ADT 22.6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190076/cannot-create-or-edit-android-virtual-devices-avd-from-eclipse-adt-22-6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be bug as of adt rev 22. It is reported and should be fixed in the next update.

Quoting Project Member

> The case of the AVD creation/repair failing when *launched from
>   Eclipse* will be fixed in ADT 22.6.1.

More info @

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66661

Quoting Project Member

**WORKAROUND:**

In Eclipse, open the SDK Manager (via toolbar or Window menu) > Tools > Manager AVDs.

This will invoke the external version of the AVD Manager which will properly generate AVDs.
Other workaround: use the command-line version (Shell or cmd.exe, cd SDK, "tools\android.bat avd").

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would install all the Build-Tools packages, that could be the problem. Also, it may take a while, I would wait a few minutes.

Comment: I do have Android SDK Build-tools v19.0.3 installed. Are you suggesting to install another version?

Comment: Nevermind, look at Raghunadan's comment. I would just wait for the next release of the SDK.