# there is a mistake in creating a android AVD?

Tags: android, android-emulator

everyone.

I'm tring to create a android AVD, the parameters seem all ok.
but when I click the button "OK" , it happen nothing, no AVD was created.

PS:the button "OK" IS NOT grey, I can click it.

how to solve it?

thx in advance.

I use : android-sdk_r22.6-linux

Comment: updated adt to rev 22??

Comment: @Raghunandan yes,android-sdk_r22.6-linux.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot create or edit Android Virtual Devices from Eclipse (OK button "WORKS")](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190076/cannot-create-or-edit-android-virtual-devices-from-eclipse-ok-button-works)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, there is a way to solve it:
create virtual device with command `android avd` instead of eclipse.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66661   #13