# Can't create any AVD on SDK 22.6

Tags: android, sdk, android-emulator, adt, android-virtual-device

It's really weird.

Ever since I've updated to the new ADT&SDK (22.6.0), I can't create any AVD. Not even the built in ones. I tried setting different Android Os versions, different memory values,... I've played with many configurations . Nothing helped.

I've tried to even uninstall and re-install the entire SDK manager, and it didn't work.

it lets me fill all of the fields, but pressing "OK" doesn't do anything. it doesn't even close the window.

Here's a sample screenshot:

[image]

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Which OS (Win 8/Linux/Mac) are you using?

Comment: Known bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66661

Comment: @MorrisonChang Windows 8.1 pro (64 bit).

Comment: @NickT so what can I do in order to solve it? is there any workaround ?

Comment: Workaround is to run AVD from outside Eclipse.

Comment: @NickT run it? but i can't even create it...

Comment: it is a known issue, please follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190076/cannot-create-or-edit-android-virtual-devices-avd-from-eclipse-adt-22-6/22198007#22198007

Comment: Sorry, I meant run AVD Manager, which is a .exe if you are on Windows.

Comment: i see. will try it out. thanks people.

Comment: @NickT ok, it works, but for some reason some AVD configurations cause the emulator to never start (or i'm too impatient for this). I'm not sure which, but i think it has something to do with Android version or ability to use snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so it seems it's a known bug.

for now, the workaround is to create the AVDs via the AVD manager, by running the AVD manager outside of eclipse- just run "AVD Manager.exe" and that's it.