# Can't create/start AVD

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I am new in this forum.
I have looked for my problem in this forum and by googling , but I haven't solved my problem yet.

When I try to create my first AVD, I can't press the "OK" button to create it.
Here you are to screenshots of my windows. The "OK" button in available, but no actions start when I press it.

I have just tried to download packages, restart Eclipse, restart PC, run directly the AVD Manager, but it does not work.
Another information: if I try to launch my first app (helloworld) the window simulates app charge only at 50%

Last information: logcat writes me:
...
tag: trace      error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
tag: gralloc_goldfish   Emulator without GPU emulation detected
...

Any suggestions?

Thank you so much.

Andrea

Comment: When you create the AVD, do you have all the required fields populated? Target Android Version, Name, and the like? What do you mean "charge app"? Battery charge? If so, that's fine, it's an emulator, that's what it "emulates".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190076/cannot-create-or-edit-android-virtual-devices-avd-from-eclipse-adt-22-6

Answer (score 0):

This workaround is from [Raghunandan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/653856/raghunandan).

In Eclipse, open the SDK Manager (via toolbar or Window menu) > Tools > Manager AVDs.

This will invoke the external version of the AVD Manager which will properly generate AVDs. Other workaround: use the command-line version (Shell or cmd.exe, cd SDK, "tools\android.bat avd").

Answer (score 0):

type in **AVD Name** field a unique word without barspace.

For example: **prima_feriferica** *instead of* **prima periferica**.
Use underscore if you need.
ciao