# When i Update Eclipse it Doesn't allow to create AVD even pressed ok still it is not creting AVD?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have updated my eclipse from help and check for new update  and now when I try to create a new AVD , Even when I press ok, nothing happens. As you can see ,my AVD shows repairable devices. But when clicked repair, nothing happens.

[image]

ANd When I try to create a new AVD Even after clicking OK nothing happens.
As you can see, ok is clickable. But when clicked nothing happens.

[image]

I have installed all the files through SDK manager under each version. 
Any solution?

Comment: Check this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190076/cannot-create-or-edit-android-virtual-devices-avd-from-eclipse-adt-22-6

Answer (score 0):

If you have updated your ADT to `ADT 22.6` then i would suggest you to use lower version like `ADT 22.3` or something else because this is a **bug from Google side**.

You can check more about this issue here in this link

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66661

To download lower version visit this link

[Cannot create or edit Android Virtual Devices (AVD) from Eclipse, ADT 22.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190076/cannot-create-or-edit-android-virtual-devices-avd-from-eclipse-adt-22-6)

and check **update 5**, there you will see download link for **ADT 22.3.0**

Answer (score 0):

As many posts say this is a bug related to the new version of ADT, I did not want to rollback and test/use a different version. For me it worked by going directly in the Android SDK folder and launching the AVD manager (AVD Manager.exe) or from SDK manager -> Tools -> Manage AVDs. Meanwhile will wait for a fix related to the ADT plugin.