# Android Virtual Machine Does Not Create in Eclipse

Tags: android, adt, android-sdk-tools

I downloaded latest Eclipse and Android SDK packages in full (including ARM System Image) and coupled them with ADT. But I couldn't create virtual machines. When I click "OK" it does not happen anything. Is there any reason behind this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot create or edit Android Virtual Devices (AVD) from Eclipse, ADT 22.6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190076/cannot-create-or-edit-android-virtual-devices-avd-from-eclipse-adt-22-6)

Comment: This issue has been fixed in SDK 22.6.1 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in the latest SDK version, you need to access to the ADT manually

```
cd path_of_android/tools/
```

and then type

```
android avd
```

Answer (score 0):

select android sdk manager from the window tab in eclipse, then once that is launched, open up tool from the top menu, then create your virtual device from there. I don't know why this works but I was able to create a virtual device using this workaround.

Comment: Yes. It should work in that way. But due to some bug in the latest SDK, it won't work in that way.

Answer (score 0):

Google has accepted this is an issue in SDK 22.6 and promised to fix it in 22.6.1 release.