# I can't create a new emulator (Eclipse - Android)

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation

I'm trying to create a new emulator in Eclipse with Android but when I press the Ok's button error log shows this error (Unhandled event loop exception):

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/sdklib/repository/descriptors/IdDisplay
at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.widgets.AvdCreationDialog.createAvd(AvdCreationDialog.java:1180)
at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.widgets.AvdCreationDialog.okPressed(AvdCreationDialog.java:972)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.buttonPressed(Dialog.java:476)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:628)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4170)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3759)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:826)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:802)
at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.widgets.AvdSelector.onNew(AvdSelector.java:898)
at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.widgets.AvdSelector.access$100(AvdSelector.java:84)
at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.widgets.AvdSelector$2.widgetSelected(AvdSelector.java:272)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4170)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3759)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:140)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:611)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
```

What can I do to solve it? I have tried many possible solutions (I tried to remove my eclipse folder and .android folder)

Comment: If you are using the latest SDK tools and plugin (22.6), the it's a known bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66661 You can run AVD Manager outside Eclipse to create an AVD

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot create or edit Android Virtual Devices (AVD) from Eclipse, ADT 22.6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190076/cannot-create-or-edit-android-virtual-devices-avd-from-eclipse-adt-22-6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to my comment, seems post #10 in [Issue 66661](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66661) that I referred to, has identical error log to yours

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2014-03-05 21:25:58.203
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/sdklib/repository/descriptors/IdDisplay
    at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.widgets.AvdCreationDialog.createAvd(AvdCreationDialog.java:1180)
    at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.widgets.AvdCreationDialog.okPressed(AvdCreationDialog.java:972)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.buttonPressed(Dialog.java:472)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:624)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
    ...
```

So it looks like you ***are*** using 22.6. Therefore just run AVD Manager from outside Eclipse until they release a 22.6.1 to fix this bug

Comment: Thanks, I could solve the problem with your solution!

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to remove android-sdk and install it again?

Regards

Comment: I haven't got any installation, I have a Eclipse folder and Android SDK folder

Comment: For install it again, i wanna say for you delete Android SDK Folder, Download a new one, and setup in eclipse android plugin the new location of android-sdk.

Comment: Download and install using the Bundle, don't try to download the individual packages (you may need to download Java separately).