# Android Virtual Device Issue

Tags: android, eclipse, android-2.2-froyo

I have been trying to create a new virtual device to test my first app using eclipse and android sdk. I did follow what is mentioned in the android sdk api documentation to create a new virtual emulator.

**Issue:**
Clicking **OK** button does nothing other than staying as is ( Configuration Image)

Can someone advise on this ?

[image: Configuration]

[image: package and image]

Comment: It is not clear what your issue is.

Comment: Have you got 2 gigs of free space on the relevant drive? On Windows ACDs are usually stored in `c:\users\username\.android\avd` Try setting a smaller amount of internal and sd card storage.

Comment: @KenWolf, If i get it correct, I have more than 2 GB in my C drive where I install eclipse. This is the only drive available in my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ADT 22.6, then it's [a known issue.](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66661) You can create the AVD by running the AVD Manager outside Eclipse.

Comment: I downloaded latest version of ADT. However, I am not sure how to check the version since it is been integrated with eclipse in my case.

Comment: In Eclipse, Click Help, the Install New Software, then click the link for 'What is already installed'. That shows you version numbers for everything there.

Comment: Thanks for that. The Android Development Tools 22.6.0.v201403010043-1049357, Eclipse is on 4.3.0, Sclipse SDK on 2.0.2.201xxxx. Can you advise me a working version of ADT. Sorry i am in process of getting my first HelloWorld out.

Comment: 22.3 works. If you read all the answers to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190076/cannot-create-or-edit-android-virtual-devices-avd-from-eclipse-adt-22-6 You will find out how to uninstall 22.6 and install 22.3

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to run the AVD? If so you just need to go to the following, highlight it and then click start.

From the menu Window -> Android Virtual Device Manager

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've just had this same issue a few days ago. Most of the answers around deal with the issue of grayed-out OK button, but that's not the case here.

Anyway, for me, the solution was to restart Eclipse / AVD manager. As simple as that.

However, that may not work right away. In this case you need to run AVD manager as a standalone .exe from Explorer, not from Eclipse.

Comment: @Veils, Can you advise me on how to run AVD manager as a standalone .exe

Comment: It's in the SDK directory, where you installed it. If you can't remember, start it from eclipse and then right click on it in task manager / open file location.