# AVD not showing home screen

Tags: java, android, eclipse

> I am using android 4.2 version 17 sdk bundle. Also, using the eclipse with it. Just extracted the zip file and copied the inside folders into my c drive- Eclipse is one folder, another is sdk. But left the unzipped file as it is which means i didn't only move the SDK manager. In eclipse, i gave the path for sdk folder(Which is C:\sdk). And in  system environment-

**User variable:**

```
Variable name: PATH
Variable value: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_32\bin
```

so, java path is right i think. Because if i run the command: java - version or javac -version, it shows the java/javac 1.6 versions

**Under System variable(in path variable) i added/edited:**

```
C:\sdk\tools;C:\sdk\platform-tools
```

But, nowhere its showing error. Still, AVD is not showing home screen. I can create it and start it. But that's it really. Not showing home screen.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall the whole bundle. That helped me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @WouterJ Actually, I think it _does_ attempt to answer the question

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat it does try, but it's just a "try X, it may works" answer, which shoukd be placed in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

Whao, that was weird. Never faced these sort of problems. Tried both os setup & SDK fresh setup-several times with several APIs. Nothing worked.

Finally when i changed the device configuration in AVD manager to-"2.7" QVGA slider(240*320 ldpi)" then it worked.

Idk, how it became possible. But its working. Hope this solution helps some one, who will face my problem(wish any one doesn't!!).