# Error on click of AVD manager icon

Tags: android

I installed android on my system today. I initially installed android sdk manager 22.6 since the AVD's cannot be created with that version i downgraded to version 22.3.

After that when I click the AVD manager icon I am not able to get the window in which we create the AVD's. Following is error which is displayed :

An internal error occurred during: "Check Android SDK".
com.android.sdklib.SdkManager.getLocalSdk()Lcom/android/sdklib/repository/local/LocalSdk;

When i click the SDK manager also i get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Try re installing it or Download and install new ADT v22.6.1  or use SDK manager to update

Take a look at following link it will definitey help you [AVD Problem Solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190076/cannot-create-or-edit-android-virtual-devices-avd-from-eclipse-adt-22-6)

Comment: Hi,When i upgrade to 22.6.1 once again i am not able to create avd.